# Best way to encrypt on a server (PHP), and decrypt on the client (Lua)?

Tags: php, lua

What is the best way to encrypt, say, a string on a server (PHP) with a 'key' - that when this encrypted string is transferred to a client (Lua), the client can decrypt this string back to normal with the same 'key'?

This way, when data is transferred from server-to-client, the user can not interrupt this process and read straight data from the request? HTTPS isn't an option for us.

Thanks.

Comment: This is subject to opinion.

Comment: Why isn't HTTPS an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AES (or a similar symetric algorithm) for encryption. AES in Lua is available as an external library(i.e. [aeslua](http://luaforge.net/projects/aeslua/)). In PHP you could use the [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.mcrypt.php) library.